# How many logs can you fit into a number?

Tags: code-golf, math, number

### Challenge

Given a real number as input, calculate the number of times which the natural logarithm function `ln` can be applied to it before the resulting number becomes imaginary.

### Explanation

Applying `ln` to a negative number results in a non-real number. This means that, by repeatedly applying `ln` to a number, you will eventually get an imaginary number. For example, using 10 as input:

```
ln(10) = 2.303                - 1 time
ln(2.303) = 0.834             - 2 times
ln(0.834) = -0.181            - 3 times
ln(-0.181) = pi*i + ln(0.181) - stop; result is 3
```

### Test cases

```
10 -> 3
1000000 -> 4
2.4 -> 2
-1 -> 0
0 -> 0
```

### Details

- This is code golf, so lowest byte answer wins.
- The input number could be negative, so `0` should be returned.
- Your solution may be either:

  - a function, which takes the input number as a parameter and returns the number of times `ln` can be applied;
  - or a program, which takes STDIN/command line argument input and prints the result.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can use the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to make sure your (future) challenges are good before posting.

Comment: @user202729 Agreed, this is a dupe - I didn't realise that this process actually had a name.